# Getting double logs in python logger - code has circular dependencies

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I am getting duplicate (double) logs when using the python logging. I have 3 files :

```
         1. main.py
         2. dependencies.py
         3. resources.py
```

I am making only 1 call to the python logger constructor which is done inside the main.py

Following are my import statements in the 3 files

main.py

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

from configparser import ConfigParser
from Craftlogger import Craftlogger

logger = Craftlogger().getLogger()
```

dependencies.py

```
import os,sys

from main import getJobDetails,postRequest,logger
from configparser import ConfigParser
```

resources.py

```
import os,sys
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
```

And inside the main method in the main.py, I have the imports

```
def main():

    from resources import getResourceDetails,setResources
    from dependencies import setDependencies


    ..... Remaining code .....
```

My logging file looks like this

```
import logging

class Craftlogger:

    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        formatter_string = '%(asctime)s | %(levelname)-8s | %(filename)s-%(funcName)s-%(lineno)04d | %(message)s'
        formatter = logging.Formatter(formatter_string)
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        self.logger.addHandler(handler)
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        self.logger.propagate = False


    def getLogger(self):
        return self.logger
```

Note : I had to do the imports inside of main so as to be able to do circular imports.

Comment: Reorganize your code. Move the functions from main to an other module. In general avoid imports from module that have a "main role". And BTW the `logger` should be initialized per module from `logging.getLogger(__name__)`.

Comment: Most of the time, duplicated logger outputs come from either propagation or duplicated handlers . You're most probably in the second case... The first thing to do (except fixing your circular dependencies as explained by Klaus D.) would be to trace `CraftLogger.__init__()` - and probably fix it to avoid adding a new handler to the same logger on each instanciation. Actually, just getting rid of it and using dedicated loggers and `DictConfig` might be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that two `CraftLogger` objects exist and both have the same `self.logger` member. `logging.getLogger(__name__)` probably returns the same object for another `CraftLogger` object, resulting in two `addHandler` calls on the same logger. This is just a guess, no guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

Logging is a cross cutting concern. As such, I frown upon classes which set up logging on their own. The responsibility to configure logging (especially handlers) should be solely with the main executing function, e.g. your main function. No submodule / class / function should modify logging, except getting a logger via logging.getlogger(**name**).
This avoids most of these pitfalls and allows easy composition of modules.
Imagine you have to import two modules who both modify the logging system...fun